# What does the "-1" mean in " if result.endswith("\n") == -1:"?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I found this code in a book. What's happening in the first `if` statement?

```
result_dirs = list(difflib.unified_diff(dirs1, dirs2))
result_files = list(difflib.unified_diff(files1, files2))

for result in result_files:
    if result.endswith("\n") == -1:
        if result.startswith('+'):
            resultadd = result.strip('+')
            added_files.append(resultadd)
        elif result.startswith('-'):
            resultsubtract = result.strip('-')
            removed_files.append(resultsubtract)
```

Comment: Either you've pasted it here incorrectly, or that book is wrong. `str.endswith()` never produces `-1`.

Comment: some C functions return `-1` and it means "error" or "no result" . In Python `string.find(substring)` returns `-1` and it means "not found".

Answer (score 0):

This statement is incorrect, since endswith method may return either True or False.
This expression must look like:
if result.endswith("\n") == False:
Here will be the check is the result doesn't finish with '\n' character.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow!  Thanks for your contribution!  One way to improve the readability of posts on SO is to use backticks to do inline code formatting -- like this `if result.endswith("\n") == False`.  You can also set off blocks of code with the `{}` button in the editor.